# Airdrop is Very Expensive

Tags: gas-price, airdrop

Cannot figure out why my Airdrop is costing so much gas. Testing on the Binance Smart Chain even when I try to send to just a few addresses metamask alerts transaction will fail and gas limit is over 25,000,000.

```
function dropTokens(address[] memory _recipients, uint16 _amount) public onlyOwner returns (bool) {
       
        for (uint i = 0; i < _recipients.length; i++) {
            require(_recipients[i] != address(0));
            require(Token(tokenAddr).transfer(_recipients[i], _amount));
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: How many is "a few"? Do you do anything special on the `transfer`?

Comment: Figured it out. Had no tokens in the contract to send out. Thought contract would act as a bridge and send tokens from my metamask. Once I sent tokens to the contract "dropTokens" worked as expected. Thanks for the help.